# How to preserve the state of android activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding

I have two activities my `MainActivity` and some other one called `DetailActivity`. When the app is first started it opens `MainActivity` and there it binds `DataService` and makes a call to fetch some data and populate a list view.

From that list view user has a button to open so called detail view for every item in the list. Opening that detail view means starting the second activity (`DetailActivity`).

Its done like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data", dto);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

When second one is opened user is able to go back either by using back button (one left of home button on android) or by clicking back arrow in the header.

Everything works as expected except that when user comes back to `MainActivity` `DataService` is binded again and call to fetch the data is made and the list is updated. So if user is somewhere at item no. 205 he will be returned back to the start item.

Is there a way to hold the data or the state of `MainActivity` when user comes back to it that its not refreshed ?

Service is bonded like this

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    bind(DataService.class);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(connection);
}

private void bind(final Class... toBind) {
    for (final Class clazz : toBind) {
        bindService(new Intent(this, clazz), connection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}

private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(final ComponentName name, final IBinder service) {
        if (service instanceof DataService.LocalBinder) {
            dataService = ((DataService.LocalBinder) service).getInstance();
            dataService.readData();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(final ComponentName name) {
        // Empty By Default
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, English is not my first language. I have used auto-correct.

Comment: You have to use savedinstancestate in Parent Activity to Control the behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it like this

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed(); // one inherited from android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

    return false;
}
```

Doing it this way seamed to do the trick. I would return to the place where I left from and there is no need to load any data since everything is already there

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by binding the service in `onCreate()` instead of `onStart()`.

You should also have a look at the symmetry of your life cycle. Currently you are binding in start and unbinding in destroy. If you bind in `onStart` you should probably unbind in `onStop`. When you move the binding to `onCreate` you can keep the unbinding in `onDestroy`

Explanation: `onCreate()` is called when the activity is created first. `onStart()` is called every time your activity becomes visible.

Comment: I still have the same behavior. I have also noticed that onDestroy is called when I come back from second activity. I am not sure if that should happen.

Comment: If your device is low on memory or "don't keep activities" in the developer options is on then your activity will be destroyed when it becomes invisible and recreated when it becomes visible. You can save the state of your activity for these cases by implementing 'onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)'. You can put primitive values or serializable or parcelable objects in the bundle and you get that bundle delivered back to you in the parameter of 'onCreate'. You could for example save your index of the scrolled item there and then scroll programmatically to it once your data was fetched again.